# NEO4J execute severals statement

Tags: neo4j

How it's possible to run a collection of query like this (came from a spreadsheet copy) directly in one cypher query?  one by one it's ok, but need 100 copy/paste

```
*******************************
MATCH (c:`alpha`)
where c.name = "a-01"
SET  c.CP_PRI=1, c.TO_PRI=1, c.TA_PRI=2
return c ;

MATCH (c:`beta`)
where c.name = "a-02"
SET  c.CP_PRI=1, c.TO_PRI=1, c.TA_PRI=0
return c ;

and 100 other lines ...

*********************************
```

Comment: You can just load this with the `bin/neo4j-shell -file update.cql` or paste or pipe it into the neo4j-shell

Answer (score 2):

you may try the 'union' clause, which joins the results of queries into one big-honkin result set:

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-union.html

That said - the root behavior of what you are trying to do could use some details - maybe there's a better way to write the query - you could use Excel to 'build' the unified query via calculations / macros, you could possibly write a unified query that combines the rules you are trying to follow, there's a lot of options, but it's hard to know a starting direction w/o context....

Comment: UNION is a work-around, but doable.  Not clear OP really cares about the result sets.  He/she might be better off putting all of the individual queries into a single text file and executing via neo4j-shell.  The copy/paste comment OP makes is questionable...

Answer (score 1):

Talking about the REST API you can use the [`transactional` endpoint in Neo4J 2.0](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-transactional.html), or the [`batch` endpoint in Neo4J 1.x](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.9.7/rest-api-batch-ops.html).

If you want to use the shell, have a look to the [import page](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/import), in particular the [neo4j-shell-tools](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#import-data-into-your-neo4j-database-from-the-neo4j-shell-command) where they're importing massive quantity of data batching multiple queries.